Problem with the way the .suffix works with SwiftData
Ok, I have a subview, which should just show 2 last readings...
I understand, that I can actually do .last and or just do $0 and $1, but I wanted to do it in an elegant way, so my code is:
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct LastReadingsView: View {
    
    var readings: [Reading]?
        
        var body: some View {
            if let readings = readings?.sorted(by: { $0.date > $1.date }) {
                
                let lastTwoReadings = readings.suffix(2)
                
                ForEach(lastTwoReadings) { reading in
                    ReadingRow(reading: reading)
                }
            } else {
                Text("No readings available")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
        }
}

#Preview {
    LastReadingsView()
}

But, it doesn't do the last two readings in an already sorted array, it takes some two elements and that is it...
Do I miss something? I know, that SwiftData is not good with array sorting, but not THAT bad?!

Because if it was a normal array, then it gets normal sort. in SwiftData, if you do ForEach for the SwiftData array - it will always show different order

Although your code works for me in my tests, you could try this approach
without using intermediate declarations in the body of the view.
struct LastReadingsView: View {
    let readings: [Reading]?
    
    var body: some View {
        if readings != nil {
            ForEach(readings!.sorted(by: { $0.date > $1.date }).suffix(2)) { reading in
                ReadingRow(reading: reading)
            }
        } else {
            Text("No readings available")
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
        }
    }
}

EDIT-1:
here is my full test code:
// for testing
@Model class Reading {
    var date: Date
    var digits: Int
    
    init(date: Date, digits: Int) {
        self.date = date
        self.digits = digits
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    // for testing
    let readingArr = [
        Reading(date: Date(), digits: 1),
        Reading(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(60*60*24*1), digits: 2),
        Reading(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(60*60*24*2), digits: 3),
        Reading(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(60*60*24*3), digits: 4),
        Reading(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(60*60*24*4), digits: 5)
    ]
    var body: some View {
        LastReadingsView(readings: readingArr)
    }
}

// test code
struct LastReadingsView: View {
    let readings: [Reading]?
    
    var body: some View {
        if readings != nil {
            ForEach(readings!.sorted(by: { $0.date > $1.date }).suffix(2)) { reading in
                ReadingRow(reading: reading)
            }
        } else {
            Text("No readings available")
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
        }
    }
}

// for testing
struct ReadingRow: View {
    let reading: Reading
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(reading.digits)")
    }
}


If you start adding to this readings..., which is an SwiftData Model array:
@Model
class Reading {
var date: Date
var digits: Int
}
then it goes all wrong

I don't see any adding to readings in your code. What does it goes all wrong mean? Show a reproducible code that we can complite, run and reproduce your problem. Currently it works very well, added my test code.

Sorry, it is really difficult to reproduce, cause the whole code of adding to the SwiftData should be written. But just believe me, it works with hardcoded numbers and totally doesn't with data in SwiftData.
Maybe it has something to do with the way the ArraySlice works in Swift or the way if does Query

Sorry, you were right... it is just that for my model, I had to use .prefix, that it why if gave me not the results that I wanted

The underlying problem is that when we use a @Query which I assume is done in the parent view then the order of the result is random unless we supply sort descriptors.
There are two ways to solve this, sort directly in the query in the parent view or sort in a computed property in the LastReadingsView
First the query solution where we add sorting to the query, this option has the best performance if there are a lot of Reading objects
@Query(sort: [SortDescriptor(\Reading.date, order: .forward)]) var readings: [Reading]

and then in the sub view we do (shortened the code for clarity)
let readings: [Reading]

var body: some View {
    ForEach(readings.suffix(2)) { reading in
        ReadingRow(reading: reading)
    }
}

For the second solution we pass the query array as today and sort it in computed property instead
let readings: [Reading]

var lastTwoReadings: [Reading] {
    readings.sorted(using: KeyPathComparator(\.date, order: .forward)).suffix(2)
}

var body: some View {
    ForEach(lastTwoReadings) { reading in
        ReadingRow(reading: reading)
    }
}

Note that in both case that reading is a non-optional constant since it won't change and it makes for cleaner code with a non-optional property
